# Regex in express

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I am not really good at Regex and I am trying to use it to match the url in express.js.

So the params will have two formats

1. ABC (All uppercase letter)
2. ABC_CBA (Use an underscore between two words, also all in uppercase)

Now I have this code

```
server.patch(/^\/a_id\/([A-Z]\w*_[A-Z]\w*)\/b_id\/([1-9]\d*)\/?$/,
        req.body);
```

With this I can handle case 2, and I try to make part 2 optional.

```
server.patch(/^\/a_id\/([A-Z]\w*(_[A-Z]\w*)?)\/b_id\/([1-9]\d*)\/?$/,
        req.body);
```

Just add a parentheses for that and add a ? at the end to specify this is optional. But now if I made a patch request to this url `/a_id/ABC_CBA/b_id/1`.

The req.params becomes `{ '0': 'ABC_CBA', '1': '_CBA', '2': '1' }`

Don't know why it matches twice for the first parameter. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like this? https://regex101.com/r/W9pnje/1

Comment: Group[ 2 is imbedded inside group 1. `(hello (world))` gives `['hello world','world']` Change it to `/^\/a_id\/([A-Z]\w*)(_[A-Z]\w*)?\/b_id\/([1-9]\d*)\/?$/`

Comment: @S.Kablar This works great! Thank you so much! Just want to clarify, so instead of just wrapped it up and have a `?` at the end, I still have to have `?:` at first?

Comment: Yes. `(?:)` is non capturing group and `?` if it exist, match.

Comment: @sln I tried yours and the req.params became `{ '0': 'ABC', '1': undefined, '2': '1' }`.... I guess it tries to match twice because there are two separate parentheses?

Comment: @S.Kablar I see, thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that this term `[A-Z]\w*` will absorb the entire `ABC_CBA` part of your string. If you want to find them separately, use this `/^\/a_id\/([A-Z][^\W_]*)(_[A-Z]\w*)?\/b_id\/([1-9]\d*)\/?$/` which gives this `**  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 : len 20 ) 
/a_id/ABC_CBA/b_id/1  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 6 : len 3 ) 
ABC  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 9 : len 4 ) 
_CBA  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 19 : len 1 ) 
1`

Comment: Please answer as an answer, not in comments

Comment: @sln Sorry I didn't explain it well. I want it to find them together. For example, `/a_id/ABC_CBA/b_id/1`. The params should be `{ '0': 'ABC_CBA',  '1': '1' }`. I only want to have two params in my req.params. But you're right that `[A-Z]\w*` will match the whole part!